# How can you refer to a class method in the 'header' of another class method as a default variable?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I am working on a class, where I would like to achieve something that broadly looks like this:

```
class Class:
   def __init__(self, x = 4):
      self.x = x

   def Square(self):
      return self.x ** 2

   def MathsOperator(self, operator = self.Square):
      return operator()
```

Note that the above class I've only just created for the purpose of illustrating what I would like to achieve. Essentially, I would like to have a method that takes in other methods, but has a default method set from within the same class. So here, `self.MathsOperator` is a method that can take any method by using the parameter `operator`. However, by default it is set to the method `self.Square`.

I have tried replacing `self.Square` with `Class.Square`, but this does not work either.

Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is only defined with a method's scope, so as you can see you can't use it in the default arguments clause. You could pass `Square` (without the `self`), but note you'll need to pass `self` when calling it:

```py
def MathsOperator(self, operator = Square):
    return operator(self)
```